# Whether an <html >tag is required in header?

Tags: theme-development, html

can i have a structure like below?

```
<div>
 <head>
 </head>
 <html>
   <body>
   <body
 </html>
<footer>
</footer>
</div>
```

I am asking this because elementor theme editor when ever some content is placed it creates `<html><body>`...if i put `<html>`in header.php this results in validation failure in validator.w3.org

Comment: That's invalid HTML, so no, you shouldn't create such code. What browsers do with that is pretty much undefined.

Comment: @fuxia thanks , i noticed that it is not from elementor ..even if i use gutenberg it happens the same ...when ever a content is placed `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">` this tag gets inserted ..any solution to fix this?

Comment: Might be an error in your theme. Try a standard Twenty-X theme.

Comment: @fuxia yeah it's my theme mistake. an extra html is some how created when ever content is placed..any way i can check what is inserting that code

Comment: Your browser will try to correct invalid markup by inserting tags.

Comment: @Milo there is no error (without any content )when i check in validator.w3.org .but when some thing is added the content get's wrapped with <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">

Comment: @Milo i was able to find out the culprit : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/323705/responsive-class-to-all-the-images-in-the-content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Can you have such structure?**

Yes, you can have such structure.

**Is it valid HTML code?**

No, it is not.

**Will the browser render it correctly?**

Most of the browsers deal with code errors pretty well. So yes - I guess it will render correctly, but it's hard to say what errors will it cause later on. It may cause some JS libraries to work incorrectly, and so on.

**Should you write such code?**

No, definitely not. It's invalid, so it's an error and should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks, i understand.  a code <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd"> gets added when ever some content is placed..any way i can test what is causing this...nothing shows up when i use var_dump..content :( , code gets added just after <head> tag and before <body>

Comment: Actually a filter was causing this : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/323705/responsive-class-to-all-the-images-in-the-content